# Can't Install AMD Radeon R5 driver on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics, error-handling

I have a Lenovo B50-70 with an AMD Radeon R5 M230 video card.

And I have a problem with the AMD driver `fglrx_15.302-0ubuntu1_amd64_ub_14.01.deb`. When I try to install it by double clicking it via Ubuntu Software, it goes to 100%, but after that, the install button is still available.

When I try to install it via terminal, [I get an error like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFHPW.png).

Does anyone know how to install that driver?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please format your post in a proper way - use plain text instead of images!

Comment: I can't copy from a picture, so please use text (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=fglrx), but your problem is both AMD & Ubuntu dropped support for that driver years ago (from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS), so unless you want to want to use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (which is nearing EOL), you are out of luck with that driver - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD